# Atom is rearranging my import lines on save

Tags: python, atom-editor

When working on a python script, Atom rearranges my lines by moving some import lines to the top

I only have the `AutoPep8` plugin which I disabled and this still happens. I've also looked at the `Whitespace` plugin as well but it doesn't have the settings I'd expect that could cause this behavior:

**Before save**

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

"""
Random doc text
"""

import sys
import os
import math
package_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(package_path)
from parent import package
import scipy
```

**On save**

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python

import scipy
from parent import package
"""
Random doc text
"""

import sys
import os
import math
package_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(package_path)
```

I can ctl-z to undo this. Is there a way to disable/fix this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, but restart of the atom after I disabled the autopep plugin worked for me. This looks like a bug in autopep8 plugin